# Scrapy: KeyError: 'Spider not found:

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to write my first Scrapy spider and have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4jtkzHhLzY&list=PLiROGjg7UWSIu0XcH8MjW0xcT70TWK_C2&index=10&t=894s&ab_channel=JohnWatsonRooney)

I am running the command exactly as shown: scrapy crawl charnley, have a name for my spider and my spider is not called "scrapy" or anything similar so I am really confused what is wrong.

This is my error messages

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 
7, in <module>
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", 
line 154, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", 
line 109, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", 
line 162, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 22, in run
crawl_defer = self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", 
line 204, in crawl
crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", 
line 237, in create_crawler
return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", 
line 312, in _create_crawler
spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
File "C:\Users\shark\VisualStudioCodeProjects\env\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 77, in load
raise KeyError(f"Spider not found: {spider_name}")
KeyError: 'Spider not found: charnley'
```

Here is my code I am using

```
from gc import callbacks
import scrapy

class CharnleySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'charnley'
start_urls = ['https://www.charnleys.co.uk/shop/bentley-supreme-apex/']

def parse(self, response):
    for elements in response.css('#tab-description'):
        yield {
            'name': elements.css('h3::text').get(),
            'price': elements.css('div:nth-child(3)').get().replace('\n',''),    
        }
```

Comment: What command are you using? Are you running it from the project's directory? What are the contents of your `scrapy.cfg` file?

Comment: The command I am running is: scrapy crawl charnley. I am running it from the directory that contains the cfg file. the contents of scrapy.cfg is:                      [settings]
default = testScraper.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = testScraper

Comment: Go to the project's root directory open the command line and run `tree /f`, then post the output.

Comment: C:.
│   scrapy.cfg
│
└───testScraper
    │   charnleysspider.py
    │   items.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   settings.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───spiders
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │
    └───__pycache__
            settings.cpython-310.pyc
            __init__.cpython-310.pyc                 I'm not sure how to format this sorry

Comment: There's your problem. Move `charnleysspider.py` into `spiders` directory.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Sorry for asking since I'm quite inexperienced, is the correct command to move the file: mv charnleysspider.py spiders          or do I need to cd into the testScraper directory first? Kind regards

Comment: Windows: `move charnleysspider.py spiders`, Linux: `mv charnleysspider.py spiders/`.